# Disable ComboBox Animation C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox in my form (DropDown mode) that does a drop down animation when its interacted with. Unfortunately my users and I find this feature distracting and counter-productive.

Is there a way to disable a ComboBox's drop down animations?

Comment: unless you have to create your own combobox from scratch or from the standard combobox.

Comment: Override the standard combobox, there is no property for disabling this animation.

Comment: do with textbox that will display listbox bellow ..

Comment: It is a system setting, you don't get to override it in your program.  If users are annoyed by it then they'll be annoyed by *any* program animating the dropdown, not just yours.  And change the system setting.  Ask at superuser.com, mention your Windows version.

Comment: @HansPassant Well you see it wasn't always so slow/exaggerated. I don't have a problem with list drop downs normally but the newer winforms versions and WPF have such accentuated drop down animations that its painful.

Comment: It is notable that you experience this annoyance only in your program but have never thought to disable the animation before.  This may well be because you are using *too many* comboboxes.  It is an ancient control that made sense many years ago when monitors could only display 640x480 pixels.  It makes a lot less sense today.  Make sure you are not committing the common UI sin of cramming your window with too many controls.

Comment: @HansPassant No no, its the only combobox in the page but they still save time and reduce UI clutter. Especially since this combobox is a minor feature in the page (a code editor) and so it needs to take up very little space and not slow down the user.